Красивый вывод таблицы
Есть двумерный массив строк. Нужно его красиво вывести, например:
3245    6   
325 32424   
562131  245355  
32  643 

а не
3245 6
325 32424
562131 245355
32 643


То есть чисел а не строк

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26937531/15035314

А в чём "красота" первого варианта?  Колонки не выражены, числа не выровнены.  Второй вариант логичнее -- данные в строке разделены одним пробелом.

Определяете максимальную длину чисел, и выводите каждый элемент в соответствующее число позиций. Например (прижато влево):
a = [[123,4,532411],[827346, -4,225]]
for row in a:
    print("".join(f"{x:<8}" for x in row))

123     4       532411  
827346  -4      225  

